# Solution for heap exception

Tags: hibernate, memory-management, solr, heap-memory

I have an dedicated server to host my application which has a mysql,tomcat and a dedicated server application running for the solr server. The Server is having a 64gb hard disk and 4gb ram.

So now my db has increased up to 14gb and the solr index size has increased upto 4.5gb and I have increased in the heap size from the tomcat upto 4gb, But when I am try to execute a db operation m getting the jave heap space exception and the same application with a small db entries work well.

So how can i get rid of the exception without hampering my current running application and what will be the possible solution for this.

And is this exception arising due to the hibernate queries used in my application? And if yes what changes should be done such the application doesnt face this exception again as my db and solr may intend to grow.

Any suggestion is appreciable.
Thanking in advance

Exception trace :

```
[ERROR] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
x.x.action.StandardDispatchService.execute(x.x.action.Action) throws x.x.action.exception.DispatchException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2931)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1405)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:467)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2510)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2135)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1869)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3270)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1028)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:140)
      [ERROR] Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /x/dispatch (x) 57 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: x
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Connection: keep-alive
      Referer: http://x/x.html
      X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http:/x/x/
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
      Content-Length: 6554
      Pragma: no-cache
      Cache-Control: no-cache
      Cookie: JSESSIONID=685w5nqkzsap
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Can you post the Exception? Did you try to use paging in queries from your DB?

Comment: @RoiG : have updated the question with trace and the hibernate query that gave this exception was   from tableName where id = 'someNumber' . So is there any way to fix this?

Comment: and the exception trace mentioned here is from my local debugging logs but with the same db and solr indexes